# Bootstrap 5 modal not working with starter template

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to implement a simple modal using the Bootstrap 5 starter template (I'm using the Bootstrap Bundle with Popper option) but for some reason, it's not working. I've gone through other similar questions but unfortunately, none of them is working for me. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I have attached the simplified code snippet. I'm trying to avoid using javascript to trigger the modal. I want to use the HTML data-* attributes to trigger the modal.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Open Modal
      </button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have had a lot of issues between BS-4 and BS-5 attributes. You should note that there are some subtle changes such as:
data-target is now data-bs-target...
data-toggle is now data-bs-toggle...
data-dismiss is now data-bs-dismiss

In your modal footer,  change to data-bs-dismiss and it should work.

Comment: @judonomi - Thank for the comment your advise worked for me.
`... data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target=...`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're probably using some older example/template. Try to use code from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#live-demo)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the strange thing is that, for example, on a mobile Kiwi browser no Bootstrap 5 modal works – including this one from your example... Of course, I tried to clear all data, reinstall, but nothing helps. While on Chrome, there's no problems. And I really don't know why: both browsers are Chromium-based...